# VideoJS - swf Loaded Metadata event

Tags: javascript, flash, video.js

I am using `videojs` to run various `flv` / `mp4` files. My code is the following:

`<div id="web_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="auto" height="auto"></div>`

```
var player = videojs('web_video', {controls: true, autoplay: false, preload: "metadata"})
            .src({type: "video/flv", src: "path/to/my/video"})

player.ready = function() {
    var video = $('#web_video_flash_api').get(0)
    video.player.on('loadedmetadata', function(){alert("Loaded!!!"}))
}
```

However the loaded metadata event is **triggered only when I press play**. Anyone have an idea how to obtain video metadata (duration, size etc) when usign the SWF player?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question, you can not get the meta data before pressing the play button because the onMetaData listener ( in the flash side ) is triggered  after a call to the [`NetStream.play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play()) method, as Adobe said [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onMetaData) :

> The associated event listener is triggered after a call to the NetStream.play() method, but before the video playhead has advanced.

Hope that can help.